# Firebase Real Time database simultaneous booking of a time slot (Overwritting problem)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make an app that books a time slot using the Real-Time database. The problem is that if 2 users select a certain time slot that is currently free, and they both click book at the same time, data is overwritten.

My booking technique is inserting a node with key = timestamp and value = userID.

So, both think that they reserved the slot for themselves, while in reality one of the booking requests overwrote the other on the database node.

I tried using the **Save data as transactions** from firebase documentation [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions). But, still slot bookings overwrite each other.

Here's my code:

```
                dbRef.child(String.valueOf(selectedDate.getTime())).runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
            @Override
            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                BookingSlot s = mutableData.getValue(BookingSlot.class);
                if (s == null) {
                    //Upload new BookingSlot
                    dbRef.child(String.valueOf(selectedDate.getTime())).setValue(s);

                          );
                    }
                    return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(BookingActivity.this,"Slot has just been booked!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //The chosen time has just been booked,

                }
                return Transaction.abort();
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                                   DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // Transaction completed
                Log.e("Booking", "postTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
            }
        });
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to assume that starting a transactions gives you a lock on a location, but that's not how transactions in Firebase work. Instead transactions in Firebase work with compare-and-set logic: the client tells you what (it thinks) the current value is, and you tell it what in that case the new value becomes by returning that new value.

So instead of calling `.setValue(s)` on the location, you should return `s` in the `MutableData`:

```
dbRef.child(String.valueOf(selectedDate.getTime())).runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
        BookingSlot s = mutableData.getValue(BookingSlot.class);
        if (s == null) {
            mutableData.setValue(uid); // TODO: pass in the UID of the user who's claiming this slot
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(BookingActivity.this,"Slot has just been booked!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return Transaction.abort();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.e("Booking", "postTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
    }
});
```

---

With the above code, the clients won't overwrite each others value.

But with Firebase you always have to consider that a malicious user might write their own code against your database, since they can find the configuration data in the APK of your app. So you should also enforce in Firebase's server-side security rules that each slot can only be claimed once.

If the bookings are stored under `/bookings`, that could be done with something like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "bookings": {
      "$timeslot": {
        ".write": "data.val() === null || data.val() === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This allows the write if either there is no value yet (the slot hasn't been claimed), or if the user writing is the one who claimed the slot before (which would allow them to clear the slot).